# Failed to write file pdf: No such file or directory (2) when using `print-to-pdf`

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a custom Dockerfile using https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome one.

```
FROM alpine:3.17

RUN apk upgrade --no-cache --available \
    && apk add --no-cache \
      chromium-swiftshader \
      ttf-freefont \
      font-noto-emoji \
    && apk add --no-cache \
      --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
      font-wqy-zenhei

# I tried with these too, same error
# RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app \
#     && adduser -D chrome \
#     && chown -R chrome:chrome /usr/src/app

# USER chrome
# WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
    CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/

ENV CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-software-rasterizer"

COPY ./app/ .

CMD ./start.sh
```

start.sh is like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# other things here

./app
```

The app starts. The app calls chrome with the below OS command (from dir `/usr/bin`):

```bash
chromium-browser --headless --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox --disable-gpu --disable-dev-shm-usage --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf='/tmp/test.pdf' /tmp/test.html
```

Chrome starts but errors with:

```
[0206/124936.861070:WARNING:dns_config_service_linux.cc(429)] Failed to read DnsConfig.\n
[0206/124936.861016:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory\n
[0206/124936.861200:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory\n
[0206/124936.868371:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.\n
[0206/124936.893388:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(385)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.\n
[0206/124936.969693:WARNING:dns_config_service_linux.cc(429)] Failed to read DnsConfig.\n
[0206/124937.140474:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(219)] Failed to write file '/tmp/test.pdf': No such file or directory (2)\n"
```

As you can see the MAIN error is: `Failed to write file '/tmp/test.pdf': No such file or directory (2)\n"`

What is causing this?

Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: Yeah. I know. I cannot really understand what is the issue. Not in Docker all this works good amazingly. Maybe a permission issues? I mean with the Dockerfile user?

Comment: How can I assign chromium-browser all permissions it needs? Just to try...

Comment: I'm talking about Dockerfile... The one I posted. Alpine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your setup and the pdf is generated fine for me from a test.html file (except the same first errors and warnings that you also have)

```
2023-03-11 14:41:24 [0311/134124.866023:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
2023-03-11 14:41:24 [0311/134124.902378:WARNING:dns_config_service_linux.cc(429)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
2023-03-11 14:41:24 [0311/134124.914149:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
2023-03-11 14:41:24 [0311/134124.914271:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
2023-03-11 14:41:24 [0311/134124.934520:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
2023-03-11 14:41:24 [0311/134124.966080:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
2023-03-11 14:41:25 [0311/134125.053836:WARNING:dns_config_service_linux.cc(429)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
2023-03-11 14:41:25 [0311/134125.111103:INFO:headless_shell.cc(107)] 4441 bytes written to file /tmp/test.pdf
```

Last log entry is `4441 bytes written to file /tmp/test.pdf` and the file is indeed generated, if I download it to my host machine I can open the pdf and it has the content of test.html.

The most probable problem with your solution is that test.html does not exists in your setup.

My setup looks like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── app
    ├── start.sh
    └── test.html
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

chromium-browser --headless --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox --disable-gpu --disable-dev-shm-usage --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf='/tmp/test.pdf' /tmp/test.html

tail -f /dev/null # <- this is for the container to run indefinitely so you can exec into it and check the contents.
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.17

RUN apk upgrade --no-cache --available \
    && apk add --no-cache \
      chromium-swiftshader \
      ttf-freefont \
      font-noto-emoji \
    && apk add --no-cache \
      --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
      font-wqy-zenhei

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
    CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/

ENV CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-software-rasterizer"

COPY ./app /tmp

RUN chmod +x /tmp/start.sh

CMD ./tmp/start.sh
```